# Sass undefined variable HEROKU Rails Application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sass

I am using Rails 4.2.1 the problem is when I run in heroku I get the error : Sass::SyntaxError: undefined variable: “$text2-font”. I have fonts in /app/assets/font.css.

The fonts.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crafty+Girls');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,700,300');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300');
```

The application.css

```
@import 'fonts.css';
@import 'font-awesome.css';
@import 'project.css';
```

The project.css.css

```
@import 'fonts.css';

$default-font: Raleway;
$text2-font: 'Open Sans';
$text-default-font: ff2;
$price-font: ff4;
$members-font: ff5;
$idea-font: ff6;

.tm {
  font-family: $text2-font;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
…
```

Production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
end
```

If I run the application locally I have no problem, but if I run in heroku I am getting the error that I mentioned before.

Comment: @spickermann I added the code of fonts.css, I am not using $text2-font in fonts. Check my update out.

Comment: Where are you calling `$text2-font` other than `project.css.css`?

Comment: @AnthonyE No, only in project.css.css, the problem is that fonts.css is not loading properly on heroku.

Comment: It must be getting called somewhere if that error is showing. If it's not being used then why is `$text2-font: 'Open Sans';` defined in `projects.css.scss`?

Comment: @AnthonyE $text2-font is defined in projects.css.scss and it is only used in the same file.  'Open Sans' is defined in font.css, however, 'Open Sans' is not recognized in project.css.scss, make sense? (take a look at the updated post)

Comment: the problem actually lies in config/intializers/assets.rb or config/environments/production.rb

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( * )`
You shouldnt precompile all, instead selectively precompile additional assets as needed